# Reorder existing activity to the top when start it from other applications

Tags: android

I have application A, and application B.

In A, it has a, b, c activities.

In B, it has x activity and there is a button to launch b activity in A.

Assume in back stack there are already activities a, b, c (c at the top) in task 1.

Now get c to start an activity x, result in x is created in task2. (Based on what I read from [the introduction](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en) on lollipop).

Then click the button in x, it will start b activity. b is then created in a separate task. I consider it normal because the launch mode is standard. If I launch b with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` flag (For some reasons, I cannot give b `singleTask` launch mode, so use the flag instead). b is brought to front, however, c is killed (Based on what I read, this is expected behavior).

Now I want to know how can I just reorder b to the top without destroying c? which will make the back stack become a, c, b.

I have tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a blank activity in application A, which is called by x, this brings task 1 to the top, then in this activity, I launch b with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag and finish itself or just `noHisotry` flag in manifest file.